# VPN kill switch when running on Hyper-V

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

HyperV instance running Windows 10 & built-in VPN, I would like to prevent all internet traffic in the instance that the VPN fails. This answer provides good information:

[In Windows 10 how do you ensure all traffic goes through VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/1021371/in-windows-10-how-do-you-ensure-all-traffic-goes-through-vpn/1021384#1021384)

But I get the error:

The route deletion failed: Element not found

Can something like this process be performed on a HyperV instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up successfully using

route delete [destination] MASK [mask] [gateway]

e.g.

route delete 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
route delete [destination_ip]
```

Replace [destination_ip] with the route you are trying to delete.

[source](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_removestaticroute.mspx?mfr=true)

Also please ensure you run command prompt as an administrator.